# Use XSLT to modify elements embedded in text of other elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Since I would probably botch up the terminology, I'll explain by example.

My XML source document contains elements like this:

```
<paragraph>
    This paragraph has things like <link><xref label="lbl1">this</xref></link>
    and things like <emphasis type="bold">this</emphasis>
    and <emphasis type="italic">this</emphasis>.
</paragraph>
```

Need to use XSLT to transform that to:

```
<p>
    This paragraph has things like <a href="[lbl1]">this</a>
    and things like <b>this</b>
    and <i>this</i>.
</p>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a correct, complete, short and easy solution. :)

Comment: You really want the `label` of the `xref` to become the href URL??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current two solutions are too-long and one of them is not even well-formed XML...

**Here is a short and complete solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link">
  <a href="[{xref/@label}]">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </a>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="emphasis">
  <xsl:element name="{substring(@type,1,1)}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="xref">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<paragraph>This paragraph has things like <link><xref label="lbl1">this</xref></link> and things like <emphasis type="bold">this</emphasis> and <emphasis type="italic">this</emphasis>.
</paragraph>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<paragraph>This paragraph has things like <a href="[lbl1]">this</a> and things like <b>this</b> and <i>this</i>.
</paragraph>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre!  That worked great, and helped my understanding of XSLT as well,

Comment: I just have a couple more questions:

Could you explain to me <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 

I ask because I it works great by itself, but when I threw it in after a <xsl:template match="/"> block that starts the transformation by adding new elements and selecting a few elements from the source XML, only the <xsl:template match="/"> code did anything.  The new code didn't produce output.  Are these incompatible?

Comment: Also, the source doc is in its own namespace, so I had to reference the elements with that namespace (match = "mydoc:link"), and now the output includes xmlns="" attributes in the output.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Thanks!!

Comment: @Dimitre 

Scratch that! I've scrapped the beginning part and rewritten it using the method applied in the answer. Much cleaner. (For anyone interested, the first block that matched the document root was missing the <xsl:apply-templates> call.)

My second question still remains, but the mysteriously-added xmlns="" attribute now only appears in the 2nd output element (after the root element with the desired xmlns attribute). Any leads on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

Comment: @zori: Read about the `"identity rule"` http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html . This is the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern and more than half of the questions tagged "xslt" are answered using this design pattern -- just read and learn. As for your namespace nodes problems, the best thing you can do is ask a separate question and explain well (with examples).

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks again Dimitre. I was actually having trouble getting relevant results searching on node()|@* because I can't get google to recognize punctuation. That link helps immensely. I was also thinking that my second question needed to be in a new post with examples, so will do!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <xsl:element name="p">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="link">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xref">
    <xsl:element name="a">
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@label" /><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="emphasis">
    <xsl:variable name="elementName">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@type='bold'">
          <xsl:text>b</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="@type='italic'">
          <xsl:text>i</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>    
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($elementName)>0">
      <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Points for doing what the OP said, but I don't think he meant it literally: putting square brackets around the value of the `href`. I can't think of a situation where that would ever be desirable.